# How can only the latest values in time windows of a pandas DataFrame be selected?

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I have a DataFrame that should be split into time windows of 15 minutes, perhaps by labeling them using a new column that has a unique identifier for each window. Then I want to keep only the latest measurements of each time window. So, if there are two measurements of "b" within a time window, only the latest one is kept, while the earlier ones are removed.

So, let's say we have the following data:

```
|**datetime**    |**measurement**|**value**|
|----------------|---------------|---------|
|2018-07-18T0642Z|"a"            |5347     |
|2018-07-18T0641Z|"b"            |8345     |
|2018-07-18T0640Z|"c"            |1256     |
|2018-07-18T0630Z|"b"            |7485     |
|2018-07-18T0629Z|"a"            |2536     |
|2018-07-18T0629Z|"b"            |5943     |
```

As a DataFrame it is this:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame(
         [
             ["2018-07-18T0642Z", "a", 5347],
             ["2018-07-18T0641Z", "b", 8345],
             ["2018-07-18T0640Z", "c", 1256],
             ["2018-07-18T0630Z", "b", 7485],
             ["2018-07-18T0629Z", "a", 2536],
             ["2018-07-18T0629Z", "b", 5943],
         ],
         columns = [
             "datetime",
             "measurement",
             "value"
         ]
    )
df["datetime"] = pd.to_datetime(df["datetime"])
df.index       = df["datetime"]
del df["datetime"]
```

With a column added to label the time windows, it becomes the following:

```
|**datetime**    |**measurement**|**value**|**time_window**|
|----------------|---------------|---------|---------------|
|2018-07-18T0642Z|"a"            |5347     |2              |
|2018-07-18T0641Z|"b"            |8345     |2              |
|2018-07-18T0640Z|"c"            |1256     |2              |
|----------------|---------------|---------|---------------|
|2018-07-18T0630Z|"b"            |7485     |1              |
|2018-07-18T0629Z|"a"            |2536     |1              |
|2018-07-18T0629Z|"b"            |5943     |1              |
```

Now, only the most recent measurements in each window are kept, meaning that the first "b" measurement of time window 1 is removed:

```
|**datetime**    |**measurement**|**value**|**time_window**|
|----------------|---------------|---------|---------------|
|2018-07-18T0642Z|"a"            |5347     |2              |
|2018-07-18T0641Z|"b"            |8345     |2              |
|2018-07-18T0640Z|"c"            |1256     |2              |
|----------------|---------------|---------|---------------|
|2018-07-18T0630Z|"b"            |7485     |1              |
|2018-07-18T0629Z|"a"            |2536     |1              |
```

How could this be achieved in Pandas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe need:

```
print (df)
           datetime measurement  value
0  2018-07-18T0642Z           a   5347
1  2018-07-18T0641Z           b   8345
2  2018-07-18T0640Z           c   1256
3  2018-07-18T0630Z           b   7485
4  2018-07-18T0629Z           b   2536 <- changed a to b
5  2018-07-18T0629Z           b   5943


df['datetime'] = pd.to_datetime(df['datetime'])
#convert datetimes to 10Min precision
df['date'] = df['datetime'].dt.floor('10Min')
#remove duplicates per columns, keep only first dupe
df = df.drop_duplicates(['measurement','date'])
print (df)
             datetime measurement  value                date
0 2018-07-18 06:42:00           a   5347 2018-07-18 06:40:00
1 2018-07-18 06:41:00           b   8345 2018-07-18 06:40:00
2 2018-07-18 06:40:00           c   1256 2018-07-18 06:40:00
3 2018-07-18 06:30:00           b   7485 2018-07-18 06:30:00
4 2018-07-18 06:29:00           b   2536 2018-07-18 06:20:00

#remove helper column date
df = df.drop('date',axis=1)
print (df)
             datetime measurement  value
0 2018-07-18 06:42:00           a   5347
1 2018-07-18 06:41:00           b   8345
2 2018-07-18 06:40:00           c   1256
3 2018-07-18 06:30:00           b   7485
4 2018-07-18 06:29:00           b   2536
```

Comment: Ah super, thank you very much for your guidance on that!